# Sent email blast to wrong group. How to figure out common result from two mysql queries

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I have to fix this fast :(

I have two queries:

```
select c.customers_email_address, c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname from customers c, orders o WHERE c.customers_id = o.customers_id and o.date_purchased > subdate(now(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH) GROUP BY c.customers_email_address order by c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname ASC LIMIT 0, 150

SELECT DISTINCT c.customers_email_address, c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname FROM customers c LEFT JOIN  orders o ON c.customers_id=o.customers_id JOIN orders_products op ON op.orders_id=o.orders_id WHERE op.products_id BETWEEN 378 AND 379
```

I was supposed to use the second query but I used the first.  I caught it after the first 150 were mailed, but now I have to generate a new list that includes everyone in the first query that would NOT be represented in the 2nd, so that I can send out an apology.

Help?

THanks.

Comment: `select query2 stuff where (relevant field NOT IN (select query #1))`, basically.

Comment: Problem that I can't figure out right now is that there are multiple products to an order.  2nd query is based on products_id being in the order, first query has nothing to do with products just purchase of any kind in last 3 months.

Comment: oh oh oh... ok, so I can exclude the orders_id from 2nd query from 1st.  OK, that's good I think.  I'll try  Edit:  nope... I can't figure it

Comment: you could double check with `create table tmp_sent1 select [select1]; create table tmp_sent2 select [select2]; select * from select1 left join select2 on ... where select2.customers_email_address is null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the answer is as simple as selecting all records in query 1 that would not be in query 2...

```
select 
    c.customers_email_address, 
    c.customers_lastname, 
    c.customers_firstname 
from 
    customers c, 
    orders o 
WHERE 
    c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
    and o.date_purchased > subdate(now(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
    AND c.customers_email_address NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT c.customers_email_address
        FROM customers c 
        LEFT JOIN  orders o ON c.customers_id=o.customers_id 
        JOIN orders_products op ON op.orders_id=o.orders_id 
        WHERE op.products_id BETWEEN 378 AND 379
    )
GROUP BY c.customers_email_address 
order by c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname ASC 
LIMIT 0, 150
```

Note that query 2's column selection is pared down to only the email address.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is select your first list where `NOT IN` your second list. 
However, `NOT IN` only works when compared to 1 column. So, only select a unique identifier. Also, when you want to finish sending your nasty emails, you can use YOUR second query and add a `AND NOT IN` this list below.

```
SELECT c.customers_email_address, c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname
FROM customers c, orders o 
WHERE c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
AND o.date_purchased > subdate(now(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
AND c.customers_email_address NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT c.customers_email_address
    FROM customers c 
    LEFT JOIN  orders o ON c.customers_id=o.customers_id 
    JOIN orders_products op ON op.orders_id=o.orders_id 
    WHERE op.products_id BETWEEN 378 AND 379
) 
GROUP BY c.customers_email_address 
ORDER BY c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname ASC
LIMIT 0, 150;
```

^Looks funny mixing comma joins in there. MySQL doesn't care, though.

Comment: Curious why "nasty emails"?  Sounds kinda judgy :)  These are transactional emails to my customers, I just selected the wrong grouping.  It isn't spam (well, it turned out to be spam, but the intent wasn't spam).  I appreciate your advice on how to finish sending them, nonetheless.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be judgy, I apologize. I assumed by labeling them "blast" emails, you were actually blasting some people. Hehe I apologize. I hope it helped in the meantime.

Comment: You're right.  Poor choice of wording in the title on my part.